# Why must I cast constantly when working with Microsoft.Interop.Excel?

Tags: c#, excel

I'm just starting to play around with excel in C#, and I've noticed several mysterious things that I think are related.

For starters here's my code:

```
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
```

...

```
static void ExcelReader(string path)
{
    Excel.Application excelApplication = new Excel.Application();
    Excel.Workbook workbook = excelApplication.Workbooks.Open(path);
    Excel.Worksheet worksheet = (Excel.Worksheet)workbook.Sheets[1]; //Why the cast?
    Excel.Range cell = (Excel.Range)worksheet.Cells[1, 1]; //Another cast?
    string value = cell.Value.ToString();
    Console.WriteLine("the value in cell a1 is "+value); //I'm shocked this actually worked
}
```

Three questions:

1. As I commented in the code, I need to cast before assigning values to `worksheet` and `cell`. Why?
2. When I debug, I see that `worksheet` and `cell` both have type `System._COMObject` and their internal fields are all null. Why is that?
3. When I type `excelApplication.`, `workbook.`, `worksheet.`, or `cell.` intellisense lists the available fields and methods and knows the names of the available parameters. But it does not display the descriptions of any of the fields, methods, or parameters.

It seems to me that somehow I'm accessing the `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel` namespace, but in a way that is confusing Visual Studio.

Comment: Short answer is you don't. This was a motivating scenario for C# 4's dynamic feature. [See the documentation which has an example using Excel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/using-type-dynamic)

Comment: You could just use `var` instead of the actual class name and let it use whatever type it needs.

Comment: Does using `var` really work?

I now declare `worksheet` as `var worksheet = workbook.Sheets[1];`

But when I try to access its `Cells` property on the following line, the compiler complains that `Objects` don't have `Cells.`

Comment: I think he is just saying that `Excel.Application excelApplication = new Excel.Application();` is pointlessly ugly and verbose... use `var excelApplication = new Excel.Application();` instead. However, while `Excel.Range cell = (Excel.Range)worksheet.Cells[1, 1];` is also more verbose than necessary, since `var cell = (Excel.Range)worksheet.Cells[1, 1];` is better, you must still to cast each frequently because the values are all of type `object` as defined by the Office.Interop APIs. Again, read the link

Comment: If you are working with `.xlsx` files you may want to look in to dropping the office interop and switching to the [Open XML SDK](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Open-XML-SDK) provided by the microsoft office team to read the xml files. It is much newer and does not use and COM so it has no problems running in a service environment (if you planned on doing that)

Comment: When in doubt, consult documentation. I looked up `Workbook.Sheets` and found this page for that property's type: [Sheets interface](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.sheets.aspx). On that page it says: "The Sheets collection can contain Chart or Worksheet objects." So you have to cast to a `Worksheet` object because the compiler has no idea if you are trying to use a `Worksheet` or a `Chart` type. Try looking into the documentation for the answers to your other questions.

Comment: There is something exceedingly untrivial about the Office object model, something that everybody takes for granted but is extraordinarily hard to do in practice.  It was created over two decades ago, but still works today in spite of massive hardware and OS changes and 8 major new releases.  How do you design something that is going to last that long?  Does it make sense that a Sheets[] reference can also be a Chart or do you suspect that a Microsoft programmer went "thank heavens I can do this"?  Feature, not a bug.